# How can I retrieve the current user's UID from Firestore and compare it to another String?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Flutter and following some tutorials I've managed to create a little app. Users can make an account and post announcements about their pets. All these announcement go to the home page, which is built using a Stream. Each announcement has a field that saves the UID of the user who posted it. What I am trying to do now is make the home page display all the announcements, except for the ones the current user posts. I want to do so by comparing the .userId field in the announcements to the UID of the current user.

```
StreamBuilder(
                                stream: getUsersPets(context),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                    return Text(
                                      "Loading...",
                                    );

                                  return new ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                            buildPetsList(context,
                                                snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                                  );
                                })
```

This is how the buildPetsList function looks like:

```
Widget buildPetsList(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    final pet = Pet.fromSnapshot(document);
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size; 
    if (pet.userId == 'tLH3ZZvxOEMQkdSL63jncQgbqN32') {
      return Container(
        height: 0,
      );
    } else { ...
```

This works fine with the hardcoded UID, but I want it to be stored in a variable and comparing it that way, obviously.
I have a method inside my Auth class but I don't know how to use it to get what I want.

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
        (FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid,
      );

  // GET UID
  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }

  // GET CURRENT USER
  Future getCurrentUser() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
}
```